# Works in .js but not in jQuery code, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This one won't work (jQuery)**

```
function convert(degree) {

    var temp;

    if (degree == 'C') {
        temp = $('#c').val(temp * 9 / 5 + 32);
        $('#f').val(temp);

    } else {
        temp = $('#f').val(temp - 32 * 5 / 9);
        $('#c').val(temp);
    }
}
```

**This one works (javascript)**

```
function convert(degree) {
    var temp;
    if (degree == 'C') {
        temp = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value = temp;
    } else {
        temp = document.getElementById("f").value - 32 * 5 / 9;
        document.getElementById("c").value = temp;
    }
}
```

**HTML CODE HERE**

```
<h1>TEMPERATURE CONVERTER</h1>

<p><input id="c" onkeyup="convert('C')"> &deg; Celsius</p>

<p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')"> &deg; Fahrenheit</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using .val() correctly. It returns the value when there are no parameters, sets it otherwise. Do this:

```
function convert(degree) {

    var temp;

    if (degree == 'C') {
        temp = $('#c').val() * (9 / 5) + 32;
        $('#f').val(temp);

    } else {
        temp = $('#f').val() - 32 * (5 / 9);
        $('#c').val(temp);
    }
}
```